# What is the Swift 2+ equivalent of this one line of code

Tags: ios, swift

What is the `Swift 2+` equivalent for this line of code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25267368/4577867)?.

```
 let a:UInt16 = UInt16(bytes[0]) * 256 + UInt16(bytes[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by checking that link .. first you have to define bytes array like `[UInt8]`

```
   let bytes:[UInt8] = [0x01, 0x02]
   let a = UInt16(bytes[0]) * 256 + UInt16(bytes[1])
```

Comment: Haha.. Thanks. Not a special initializer at all!

Comment: Good answer, but shifting by 8 makes it easier to understand than multiplying by 256

Comment: @Kevin yes... but OP wants equivalent code .. which doesn't need at all... actually he doesn't initialise bytes array ... thats mistacke

Comment: @Kevin I think what you told you is this `let a = (UInt16(bytes[1]) << 8) + UInt16(bytes[0])` right

Comment: Shifting by 8 is exactly the same as multiplying by 256 (2^8), shifting is generally used when you're packing bits together.

Comment: @Kevin that answer is fine too.. but I just confused the bytes variable with some sort of initializer that took the early swift (pre 1.2 I think) Byte type, since the question was old and I didn't read it fully nor notice the lower case 'b'. Not enough sleep, probably. Either way the answer is obvious, I think.  Thanks guys.