# How would I convert a [UInt8] to [UInt16] in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a

```
var byteArr:[UInt8] = [126, 34, 119, 55, 1, 159, 144, 24, 108, 226, 49, 178, 60, 119, 133, 97, 189, 49, 111, 208]
```

How would I create a new `var newArray:[UInt16]` from that?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: Do you want to convert each byte separately, or is the intention to combine each UInt8 *pair* to one UInt16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like:

```
var byteArr:[UInt8] = [126, 34, 119, 55, 1, 159, 144, 24, 108, 226, 49, 178, 60, 119, 133, 97, 189, 49, 111, 208]

var newArray:[UInt16] = byteArr.map { UInt16($0) }
```

map performs a function on each element of an array and returns a new array

Comment: No need to declare `newArray` as `[Int16]`, that's implied by the return value of `map`.

Comment: yeah i just thought i'd make it obvious, more self documenting

Comment: You also don't need the `()` after `map`:  `let newArray = byteArr.map { UInt16($0) }`

Answer (score 6):

### `UInt8 UInt8` combined bytepattern to `UInt16`

If your intention is, as hinted by MartinR in the comments to your question, to transform pairs of `UInt8` (e.g. 8+8 bits) to a single `UInt16` (16 bits), one possible solution is as follows:

```
/* pair-wise (UInt8, UInt8) -> (bytePattern bytePattern) -> UInt16       */
/* for byteArr:s of non-even number of elements, return nil (no padding) */
func byteArrToUInt16(byteArr: [UInt8]) -> [UInt16]? {
    let numBytes = byteArr.count
    var byteArrSlice = byteArr[0..<numBytes]

    guard numBytes % 2 == 0 else { return nil }

    var arr = [UInt16](count: numBytes/2, repeatedValue: 0)
    for i in (0..<numBytes/2).reverse() {
        arr[i] = UInt16(byteArrSlice.removeLast()) +
                 UInt16(byteArrSlice.removeLast()) << 8
    }
    return arr
}
```

Example usage:

```
/* example usage */
var byteArr:[UInt8] = [
    255, 255,  // 0b 1111 1111 1111 1111 = 65535
    0, 255,    // 0b 0000 0000 1111 1111 = 255
    255, 0,    // 0b 1111 1111 0000 0000 = 65535 - 255 = 65280
    104, 76]   // 0b 0110 1000 0100 1100 = 26700

if let u16arr = byteArrToUInt16(byteArr) {
    print(u16arr) // [65535, 255, 65280, 26700], OK
}
```

---

*(Edit addition)*

For a less bloated alternative, you could use `NSData` or `UnsafePointer` as described in the following Q&A:

- [Convert a two byte UInt8 array to a UInt16 in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267089/convert-a-two-byte-uint8-array-to-a-uint16-in-swift)

(this Q&A is possibly a duplicate to this linked one)

Comment: Thank you for your time on this one, dfri. My intention was to accomplish what Scriptable had answered.