# Extract 4 bits of Bluetooth HEX Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to implement Bluetooth FTMS(Fitness Machine).

```
guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)
let nsdataStr = NSData.init(data: (characteristic.value)!)

print("pwrFTMS 2ACC Feature  Array:[\(byteArray.count)]\(byteArray) Hex:\(nsdataStr)")
```

Here is what's returned from the bleno server

`PwrFTMS 2ACC Feature  Array:[8][2, 64, 0, 0, 8, 32, 0, 0] Hex:{length = 8, bytes = 0x0240000008200000}`

Based on the specs, the returned data has 2 characteristics, each of them 4 octet long.
I'm having trouble getting the 4 octets split so I can get it converted to binary and get the relevant Bits for decoding.

[image]

Part of the problem is the swift will remove the leading zero. Hence, instead of getting `00 00 64 02`, I'm getting 642. I tried the below to pad it with leading zero but since it's formatted to a string, I can't convert it to binary using radix:2

```
let FTMSFeature = String(format: "%02x", byteArray[3]) + String(format: "%02x", byteArray[2]) + String(format: "%02x", byteArray[1]) + String(format: "%02x", byteArray[0])
```

I've been banging my head on this for an entire day and went thru multiple SO and Google to no avail.

How Can I convert:

```
From - [HEX] 00 00 40 02
To   - [DEC] 16386
To   - [BIN] 0100 0000 0000 0010
```

then I can get to Bit1 = 1 and Bit14 = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Can I convert:
>
> From - [HEX] 00 00 40 02
>  To   - [DEC] 16386
>  To   - [BIN] 0100 0000
> 0000 0010

You can simply use `ContiguousBytes` withUnsafeBytes method to load your bytes as `UInt32`. Note that it will use only the same amount of bytes needed to create the resulting type (4 bytes)

```
let byteArray: [UInt8] = [2, 64, 0, 0, 8, 32, 0, 0]
let decimal = byteArray.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }
decimal  // 16386
```

To convert from bytes to binary you just need to pad to left your resulting binary string. Note that your expected binary string has only 2 bytes when a 32-bit unsigned integer should have 4:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var binary: String {
        (0 ..< Self.bitWidth / 8).map {
            let byte = UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: self >> ($0 * 8))
            let string = String(byte, radix: 2)
            return String(repeating: "0",
                          count: 8 - string.count) + string
        }.reversed().joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

let binary = decimal.binary  // "00000000 00000000 01000000 00000010"
```

To know if a specific bit is on or off you can do as follow:

```
extension UnsignedInteger {
    func bit<B: BinaryInteger>(at pos: B) -> Bool {
        precondition(0..<B(bitWidth) ~= pos, "invalid bit position")
        return (self & 1 << pos) > 0
    }
}
```

---

```
decimal.bit(at: 0)  // false
decimal.bit(at: 1)  // true
decimal.bit(at: 2)  // false
decimal.bit(at: 3)  // false
decimal.bit(at: 14) // true
```

If you need to get a value at a specific bytes position you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47764694/2303865)

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks a Lot. Tho I fail to understand the meaning of ```ContiguousBytes withUnsafeBytes``` (still googling and reading it). I also am struggling to understand why my previous decoding method does not work.  I have posted that as a separate question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/68265831/14414215 Could you take a look as well. TQ